# Does "set off" mean "explode" or "launch the process which will lead to an explosion"?

Tags: meaning

(1), (2) & (3) are from [thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+off).

**(1)** *The boys were **setting** firecrackers **off** all afternoon*.
Does (1) mean (1a) or (1b)?:
**(1a)** *The boys were **exploding** firecrackers all afternoon*.
**(1b)** *The boys were **setting fire to** firecrackers all afternoon*.

**(2)** *They **set off** rocket after rocket*.
Does (2) mean (2a) or (2b)?:
**(2a)** *They **exploded** rocket after rocket*.
**(2b)** *They **launched** rocket after rocket*.

**(3)**  *They **set off** a bomb*.
Does (3) mean (3a) or (3b)?:
**(3a)**  *They **exploded** a bomb*.
**(3b)**  *They launched the mechanism which would make a bomb explode*.

Comment: How can boys explode firecrackers without setting fire to them?

Comment: @gotube They can't. But why did you ask it?

Comment: I asked because if they mean the same thing to you, then what's the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

Comment: @gotube The difference is obviously that the a-variants (explosions) are consequences of the b-variants (those actions which led to these explosions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of things that explode, to "set something off" always means:

> **3 b :** to cause to explode

which better dictionaries make clear, as in this quote from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set%20off).

So in all three cases, the meaning is (b).

Your question is also tricky because there's two meanings of "explode" as a *transitive* verb in the context of explosives. One meaning is the same as (i) "set off". The other means to (ii) destroy something non-explosive using explosives:

> (i) explode a bomb (the bomb explodes itself)
> (ii) explode a car (a bomb explodes the car)

Answer (score 0):

I would say "set off" in this circumstance always means "initiated".  Even in the bomb case the person simply starts whatever process actually makes the bomb explode (except, I suppose in some kind of misfire case where the action does in fact directly cause the explosion).

In fireworks cases that would be to light a fuse, in modern blasting that would likely be an electrically driven detonation system of some kind that causes blasting caps to fire that then trigger the main detonation.